# Why do we put an indefinite article "a" before Merry Christmas?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, christmas

I am wondering why there is an article -a- before Merry Christmas
Is it because it's a day or Christmas is countable?
I couldn't explain it to my students in a transparent way.

Comment: I think you're right in thinking that 'Christmas' is countable.

Comment: *Have **a** nice day, Have **a** Merry Christmas, We wish you **a** Merry Christmas*.

Comment: We also wish people a happy birthday, or a nice break (from work). Their experience of these is individual and countable,

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering why there is an article -a- before Merry Christmas

It has nothing much to do with countability:

I have a slight knowledge of French

It is far easier if you write a complete sentence, so that it makes sense:

"We had a merry Christmas this year."

"We had a terrible Christmas this year."

"We went to Australia and had a very hot Christmas this year."

An adjective has a partitive effect on its noun. It separates that adjective-type noun from all other nouns of that sort.

A/an = one example of a; one type of a, etc.

Comment: I have only slight knowledge of Serbo-Croat.